# Disable previousBtn and nextBtn when webview cannot go to previous and next page

Tags: c#, browser, uwp

I have a webview on the application that I created. I would like if webview can not go to the previous page then previousBtn not clickable and if webview can not go to next page then nextBtn not clickable. But if webview can go to the previous page, then previousBtn clickable and if webview can go to the next page, then nextBtn clickable.
I've been using the code below:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var targetUrl = new Uri("http://missindonesia.net/forum/index.app.html");
            webView.Navigate(targetUrl);
            if(!webView.CanGoBack)
            {
                previousBtn.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else if(webView.CanGoBack)
            {
                previousBtn.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else if(!webView.CanGoForward)
            {
                nextBtn.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else if(webView.CanGoForward)
            {
                nextBtn.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void webView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                busyIndicator.IsActive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ConnectionException();
            }
        }

        private async void ConnectionException()
        {
            MessageDialog messageDialog;
            messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Please check your internet connection!", "Connection Error");
            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Refresh", (command) =>
            {
                busyIndicator.IsActive = true;
                webView.Refresh();
            }));

            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Close", (command) =>
            {
                Application.Current.Exit();
            }));

            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }

        private async void webView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
        }

        private void previousBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                if(webView.CanGoBack)
                {
                    busyIndicator.IsActive = true;
                    webView.GoBack();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ConnectionException();
            }
        }

        private void nextBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                if(webView.CanGoForward)
                {
                    busyIndicator.IsActive = true;
                    webView.GoForward();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ConnectionException();
            }
        }   
    }
```

But previousBtn become clickable when webview webview can go to the previous page.
How do I solve the above problem?

Comment: Your code sets the `previousBtn` and `nextBtn` states at construction but does not update them when navigation state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Raymond Chen said, your problem is that you didn't update the states when the navigation state changes.

You will need to change the state of you Buttons for exmaple in the `webView_NavigationCompleted` event.

Here I suggest you to use data binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to change the state of your Buttons, it make the code more clear.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WebView x:Name="webView" Source="http://missindonesia.net/forum/index.app.html" NavigationCompleted="webView_NavigationCompleted" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Content="Previous" x:Name="previousBtn" Click="previousBtn_Click" Margin="30,0" Width="100" IsEnabled="{x:Bind IspreviousBtnEnable, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Button Content="Next" x:Name="nextBtn" Click="nextBtn_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="30,0" Width="100" IsEnabled="{x:Bind IsnextBtnEnable, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _IspreviousBtnEnable;

    public bool IspreviousBtnEnable
    {
        get { return _IspreviousBtnEnable; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _IspreviousBtnEnable)
            {
                _IspreviousBtnEnable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _IsnextBtnEnable;

    public bool IsnextBtnEnable
    {
        get { return _IsnextBtnEnable; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _IsnextBtnEnable)
            {
                _IsnextBtnEnable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void previousBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webView.CanGoBack)
            webView.GoBack();
    }

    private void nextBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webView.CanGoForward)
            webView.GoForward();
    }

    private void webView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (webView.CanGoForward)
            IsnextBtnEnable = true;
        else
            IsnextBtnEnable = false;

        if (webView.CanGoBack)
            IspreviousBtnEnable = true;
        else
            IspreviousBtnEnable = false;
    }
}
```

I saw `busyIndicator` in your code, I'm not sure if you're using Template 10 for development, if so, this code can be moved into the ViewModel of this page, and you can inherit from `ViewModelBase`, not `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I've tried the code above, but when webview can go to the next page or to the previous page, the button previousBtn and nextBtn still can not be clicked. I make it on the windows 10

Comment: @Rose, did you noticed this: `public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged`? You will need to inherit your class from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: i add INotifyPropertyChanged on public sealed partial class MainPage : Page and have an error message: 'MainPage' does not implement interface member 'INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'

Comment: @Rose, yes, then, did you notice this code: `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`? And you will need to add namespace for this interface: `using System.ComponentModel;`